# Not getting spacing

Tags: javascript

Why I don't get a space between red and mazda in this code?

```
var cardetails = {colour:"red", condition:"good", transmition:"auto", make:"mazda"};

document.write(cardetails.make, cardetails.colour);
```

Comment: Because you don't have any space anywhere. Can you argue why there should be a space there?

Comment: Use `document.write(cardetails.make + " " + cardetails.colour);` instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the space manually like this

```
document.write(cardetails.make + " " + cardetails.colour);
```

Neither of the strings `red` `good` `auto` or `mazda` have a space in them so you cannot expect Javascript to introduce a character in between without you explictly asking it to do so.